How to enable experimental Network View in Javascript debugger in vscode?
In vscode release 1.93 there is a new setting:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_93#_experimental-network-view
I followed the instructions, but I couldn't find the Network View.
Attached is the launch.json file I used:
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--experimental-network-inspection"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Process",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}


I also tried attaching to node v22 with the mentioned flag - but the tab Network section still didn't appear in the debugger.

What am I doing wrong?
